# Can't create table in Oracle Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I am very new to SQL and having a problem for creating the table.
I have been looking at this code for the past two days now and I can not seem to get it to work. It keeps giving me "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" I know that this is a topic that comes up a lot but for some reason none of the examples I have seen has helped me. Can someone please tell me why I got this error and how do I fix it. I am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with my parenthesis, maybe its my CONTRAINTS
Here is my Code

```
create TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Phone INT(10) NOT NULL,
JobTitle VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);


create TABLE Airplane
(
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Capacity INT(1000) NOT NULL,
Modle VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);


create TABLE Route
(
FlightID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Origin VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Destination VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ETD INT(10) NOT NULL,
ETA INT(10) NOT NULL
);


create TABLE Customer
(
CustomerID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PhoneNumber INT(30) NOT NULL
);


create TABLE Maintenance
(
MaintenanceID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
MaintenanceDate date NOT NULL,
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
);

create TABLE Flight
(
FlightID VARCHAR(10),
FlightDate date,
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10),
ATD INT(10) NOT NULL,
ATA INT(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID),
FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),
CONSTRAINT PK_FlightID PRIMARY KEY (FlightID,FlightDate)
);



create TABLE Reservation
(
ReservationID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FlightID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FlightDate date NOT NULL,
Fare float,
PaymentMethod VARCHAR(20),
CardNumber INT(30) NOT NULL,
ExperationDate date,
check (PaymentMethod = "Cash" OR PaymentMethod ="Credit" OR PaymentMethod 
="Cheque",
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
FORIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate)
);

create TABLE CrewResveration
(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10),
FlightID VARCHAR(10),
FlightDate date NOT NULL,
Role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ShiftHour INT(10) NOT NULL,
FORIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate)
FORIGNKEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) 
CONSTRAINT PK_CrewAssignment PRIMARY (FlightID,FlightDate,EmployeeID)
);
```

Here are the results I get when I run the code:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Phone INT(20) NOT NULL,
JobTitle VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 10
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 10 in command -
create TABLE Airplane
(
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Capacity INT(1000) NOT NULL,
Modle VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
Error at Command Line : 13 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 18 in command -
create TABLE Route
(
FlightID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Origin VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Destination VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ETD INT(10) NOT NULL,
ETA INT(10) NOT NULL
)
Error at Command Line : 23 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 28 in command -
create TABLE Customer
(
CustomerID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PhoneNumber INT(30) NOT NULL
)
Error at Command Line : 32 Column : 16
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 36 in command -
create TABLE Maintenance
(
MaintenanceID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
MaintenanceDate date NOT NULL,
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
)
Error at Command Line : 42 Column : 37
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 46 in command -
create TABLE Flight
(
FlightID VARCHAR(10),
FlightDate date,
AirplaneID VARCHAR(10),
ATD INT(10) NOT NULL,
ATA INT(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID),
FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),
CONSTRAINT PK_FlightID PRIMARY KEY (FlightID,FlightDate)
)
Error at Command Line : 51 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 60 in command -
create TABLE Reservation
(
ReservationID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FlightID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FlightDate date NOT NULL,
Fare float,
PaymentMethod VARCHAR(20),
CardNumber INT(30) NOT NULL,
ExperationDate date,
check (PaymentMethod = "Cash" OR PaymentMethod ="Credit" OR PaymentMethod 
="Cheque",
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
FORIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate)
)
Error at Command Line : 68 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 76 in command -
create TABLE CrewResveration
(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10),
FlightID VARCHAR(10),
FlightDate date NOT NULL,
Role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ShiftHour INT(10) NOT NULL,
FORIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate)
FORIGNKEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) 
CONSTRAINT PK_CrewAssignment PRIMARY (FlightID,FlightDate,EmployeeID)
)
Error at Command Line : 82 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: it's mysql or oracle?

Comment: Implementing the database in Oracle SQLPlus. My Bad. I'm very to all this thing.

Comment: try changing `int` datatype by `number` or `integer`, `varchar` by `varchar2`

Comment: `int` doesn't take parameters. Please read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your data types. `INT` is not a valid Oracle datatype. Try this instead:

```
create TABLE Employee ( EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
                        Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
                        Phone NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
                        JobTitle VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL );
```

Comment: `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` are functionally equivalent, according to Oracle: "The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings."

Comment: Hi i change all my INT to number already but still showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error description is misleading, but the pointer (line 5, column 10) points to exactly after reading the word "INT" ... which, is unknown by him. He should state he doesn't understand that, but he mentions something with parenthesis, which ironically are actually correct. Unfortunately, it happens on occasions that error messages are misleading, and you have to think one step further.